# How to remove leading slash (/) from imports after bundling a Vite project

Tags: typescript, vite

For example, if I have a file in my public folder that I import like so:

import something from '/file.svg

I need it to bundle as:

import something from 'assets/file.svg

But instead I am getting:

import something from '/assets/file.svg

```
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-jE1QDfYR.css">
```

slash (/) need to be before it should come like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="assets/index.css">
```

I have tried modifying vite.config.js to include any of the following:

base: '',
base: '/',
base: './',